# Strange Issue Using Logging Module in Python

Tags: python, debugging, error-logging

I seem to be running into a problem when I am logging data after invoking another module in an application I am working on. I'd like assistance in understanding what may be happening here.

To replicate the issue, I have developed the following script...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging
from oletools.olevba import VBA_Parser, VBA_Scanner
from cloghandler import ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler

# set up logger for application
dbg_h = logging.getLogger('dbg_log')
dbglog = '%s' % 'dbg.log'
dbg_rotateHandler = ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler(dbglog, "a")
dbg_h.addHandler(dbg_rotateHandler)
dbg_h.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# read some document as a buffer
buff = sys.stdin.read()

# generate issue
dbg_h.error('Before call to module....')
vba = VBA_Parser('None', data=buff)
dbg_h.error('After call to module....')
```

When I run this, I get the following...

```
cat somedocument.doc | ./replicate.py
ERROR:dbg_log:After call to module....
```

For some reason, my last dbg_h logger write attempt is getting output to the console as well as getting written to my dbg.log file? This only appears to happen AFTER the call to VBA_Parser.

```
cat dbg.log
Before call to module....
After call to module....
```

Anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening? I reviewed the [source code of olevba](https://bitbucket.org/decalage/oletools/src/2f7ed451330d9b087d678ed61611904c8de805ff/oletools/olevba.py?at=default) and did not see anything that stuck out to me specifically.

Could this be a problem I should raise with the module author? Or am I doing something wrong with how I am using the cloghandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oletools` codebase is littered with calls to the root logger though calls to `logging.debug(...)`, `logging.error(...)`, and so on. Since the author didn't bother to configure the root logger, the default behavior is to dump to `sys.stderr`. Since `sys.stderr` defaults to the console when running from the command line, you get what you're seeing.

You should contact the author of `oletools` since they're not using the logging system effectively. Ideally they would use a named logger and push the messages to that logger. As a work-around to suppress the messages you could configure the root logger to use your handler.

```
# Set a handler
logger.root.addHandler(dbg_rotateHandler)
```

Be aware that this may lead to duplicated log messages.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll put a bug in his ear and workaround as appropriate.